# MySQL order by two values

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

In short, I have a game of sorts, and the score board for it shows the score of the player at the end + how long they took to achieve it. I need to order my MySQL results so that the highest score in the fastest time is first and the lowest score with the slowest time is last, and everything in between is ranked in the same way. But I have no idea how I'd do that, here's my sql as it stands:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM boobmatch_highscores ORDER BY t_score DESC, time ASC";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The data in the table:

```
Score       Time
23        00:04:32
23        00:04:31
25        00:02:32
16        00:06:32
35        00:04:32
2         00:01:17
-13       00:19:32
-3        00:07:27
```

Comment: What results are you getting vs. what are you expecting?

Comment: Is it worse that the first thing I saw in this question was "boobmatch," or that I immediately knew what the game was?

Comment: If you can give some sample data, and what you expect the output (showing where complications may be), it would greatly help us to help you...

Comment: time is date or seconds?

Comment: Added what the table data might look like, time is in PHP time format, hours, mins, secs

Comment: You can view the leaderboard here, http://aviatex14.co.uk/boobmatch/viewhighscores.php - It seems to be working now...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You query is supposed to work perfectly. If you have any issues just enclose the field names in quotes like so:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM boobmatch_highscores ORDER BY `t_score` DESC, `time` ASC";
```

Guessing it's MySQL, else the quotes won't be necessary

Answer (score 1):

You should be use below code.. Its working.

```
$query = "SELECT field1, field2 from tablename ORDER BY field1 DESC, field2 DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use an integer column for `time` instead of a varchar,
that's mean convert `00:19:32` to just 1172 seconds,
then is pretty easy for sort

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best solution for arrange order by multiple value.

```
 SELECT * FROM hotel   
   WHERE confId=13   
   GROUP BY hotelName   
   ORDER BY CASE
   WHEN rating = '5 Star' THEN 1 WHEN rating = '4 Star' THEN 2   
   WHEN rating = '3 Star' THEN 3 WHEN rating = 'BUDGET & EQUIVALENT HOTELS' THEN 4 
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to use this query:

```
select * from boobmatch_highscores order by time ASC, t_score DESC
```

Now time is displayed ascending order and score is displayed descending order.

Answer (score -2):

just try

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM boobmatch_highscores ORDER BY t_score * time DESC";
```

Comment: And the winner is the player with the slowest time.