# SQL ordering (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

This seemingly simple order requirement does not seem to have simple solution.

I would like a table be ordered by the item with the highest max value followed by the rest of the same item in descending order. Then the item with the next highest max value followed by the rest of the same item in descending order.. etc

For example I need to order a table similar like this:

```
item   value   
 AAA    2
 AAA    4
 AAA    2
 CCC    8
 BBB    1
 BBB    2
 BBB    6
 CCC    4
```

To be ordered like this..

```
item   value   
 CCC    8
 CCC    4
 BBB    6
 BBB    2
 BBB    1
 AAA    4
 AAA    2
 AAA    2
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2b285/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`item` varchar(3), `value` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`item`, `value`)
VALUES
    ('AAA', 2),
    ('AAA', 4),
    ('AAA', 2),
    ('CCC', 8),
    ('BBB', 1),
    ('BBB', 2),
    ('BBB', 6),
    ('CCC', 4)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
     t1.*
from (
  select item, max(value) mval from table1 group by item
  ) m1
inner join table1 t1 on m1.item = t1.item
order by 
      m1.mval DESC
    , t1.item
    , t1.value DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2b285/3/0)**:

```
| item | value |
|------|-------|
|  CCC |     8 |
|  CCC |     4 |
|  BBB |     6 |
|  BBB |     2 |
|  BBB |     1 |
|  AAA |     4 |
|  AAA |     2 |
|  AAA |     2 |
```

In response to worthwhile comment below:
Here's another option that this approach permits (nb: case 'DDD' has been added)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4de473/1/0)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`item` varchar(3), `value` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`item`, `value`)
VALUES
    ('DDD', 8),
    ('DDD', 8),

    ('AAA', 2),
    ('AAA', 4),
    ('AAA', 2),
    ('CCC', 8),
    ('BBB', 1),
    ('BBB', 2),
    ('BBB', 6),
    ('CCC', 4)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
     t1.*
from (
  select item, max(value) mval , sum(value) sval 
  from table1 group by item
  ) m1
inner join table1 t1 on m1.item = t1.item
order by 
      m1.mval DESC
   ,  m1.sval DESC
    , t1.item
    , t1.value DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4de473/1)**:

```
| item | value |
|------|-------|
|  DDD |     8 |
|  DDD |     8 |
|  CCC |     8 |
|  CCC |     4 |
|  BBB |     6 |
|  BBB |     2 |
|  BBB |     1 |
|  AAA |     4 |
|  AAA |     2 |
|  AAA |     2 |
```

Comment: why the complexity when a simple ORDER BY item DESC, value DESC returns the desired results?

Comment: perhaps it isn't needed, but the approach is extensible (added to answer)

Comment: Thank you very much! ..this is what I was looking for. And the extensible solution was needed.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you seem to be looking for:

```
select item, value
from tablename
order by item desc, value desc
```

Here is a working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e56d7/1

Answer (score 1):

`select item, value from yourtable order by item desc, value desc;`

[MySQL order by two values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834658/mysql-order-by-two-values)